# Android room save custom type

Tags: android, android-room

I try save custom type in room database. I always getting an error

**error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.**

I created converter for OutboxItemCache

My entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "request")
class RequestCache(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "requestId")
    @PrimaryKey var id: String = "",
    @TypeConverters(RequestConverter::class)
    var outboxItemCache: OutboxItemCache)
```

My RequestConverter

```
class RequestConverter {
companion object {
    private val gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToOutboxItem(string: String): OutboxItemCache? {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(string))
            return null
        return gson.fromJson(string, OutboxItemCache::class.java)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    private fun outboxItemToString(outboxItem: OutboxItemCache): String {
        return gson.toJson(outboxItem)
    }

}
}
```

This my class OutboxItemCache

```
class OutboxItemCache(
    var id: String = "",
    val numder: String,
    date: String,
    val headerDate: String,
    name: String,
    val certCount: String,
    val status: String,
    val statusColor: Int,
    var statusInfo: String? = null,
    val vetCertIds: List<String>
  )
```

The error never disappeared

Comment: Did you add @TypeConverters({RequestConverter.class}) to your AppDatabase class?

Answer (score 0):

As per [google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data):

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({RequestConverter.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

You need to register your TypeConverters to your Database class.

**EDIT:**

In kotlin:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
@TypeConverters(RequestConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabse : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDAO(): UserDAO    
}
```

The only line of code here that matters to you is

```
@TypeConverters(RequestConverter::class)
```

as you should already have the others.

**EDIT 2:**

Try writing your converter class as follows:

```
class RequestConverter {
@TypeConverter
fun stringToOutboxItem(string: String): OutboxItemCache? {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(string))
        return null
    return Gson().fromJson(string, OutboxItemCache::class.java)
}

@TypeConverter
private fun outboxItemToString(outboxItem: OutboxItemCache): String {
    return Gson().toJson(outboxItem)
}
```

Comment: as it will be written on kotlin?

Comment: I register converter in Database. Get new error: RequestConverter.java:6: error: Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods.

Comment: Did you tried to make your RequestConverter.class methods public?